# Phpdocumentor - How to avoid the 'No summary ...' messages

Tags: php, phpdoc

PhpDocumentor is giving to me a lot of messages in red like this:

```
No summary was found for this file
No summary for method baseQueryString()
...
No summary for method hiddenField()
...
No summary for method clean()
...
No summary for property $speed
...
```

Though that's very useful to know where a docblock hasn't been defined, sometimes it's very annoying when searching for errors in parsing.

There's is some way to output phpdoc parsing without this kind of messages ?

Comment: [-ue option](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_phpDocumentor.howto.pkg.html)

Comment: no such option exists , at least when I'm running phpdoc. Maybe because it's phpdocumentor. I corrected the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No option exists to disable those message, yet -- https://github.com/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor2/issues/40